# Loading external scss files with next.js (react)

Tags: reactjs, npm, sass, next.js, server-side-rendering

Loading SaSS files from zeit fails with below error

```
node_modules\@zeit\next-css\node_modules\mini-css-extract-plugin\dist\index.js:21} = _webpack2.default;
^TypeError: Cannot destructure property `createHash` of 'undefined' or 'null'.
```

next.config.js

```
const withCSS = require("@zeit/next-css");
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass')

module.exports = withCSS(withSass({
    webpack (config, options) {
      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg|eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'url-loader',
          options: {
            limit: 100000
          }
        }
      })

      return config
    }
  }))
```

stylesheets resides under src > stylesheets folder

Refering to https://dev.to/harveyjones282/the-simplest-way-to-configure-next-js-with-sass-3en

Appreciate any feedback :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed after installing latest next.js package

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same error some time ago, and I don't exactly remember how I landed here but this code works -

```
const withSASS = require('@zeit/next-sass')

const { parsed: localEnv } = require('dotenv').config()
const webpack = require('webpack')

function HACK_removeMinimizeOptionFromCssLoaders(config) {
  console.warn(
    'HACK: Removing `minimize` option from `css-loader` entries in Webpack config',
  )
  config.module.rules.forEach(rule => {
    if (Array.isArray(rule.use)) {
      rule.use.forEach(u => {
        if (u.loader === 'css-loader' && u.options) {
          delete u.options.minimize
        }
      })
    }
  })
}

module.exports = withSASS(
  {
      webpack(config) {
        HACK_removeMinimizeOptionFromCssLoaders(config)
        config.plugins.push(new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin(localEnv))

        return config
      }
  }
)
```

Try using replacing the code in your next.config.js file with this, install the necessary dependencies like dotenv, next-sass. And re run your server for the changes to take effect.